# How to make raspbian load the i2c-dev module on boot up

Tags: raspbian, i2c, modules

I have installed 2012-07-15-wheezy-raspbian, and the i2c-dev module and i2c_bcm2708
 are there and work with i2c-tools.

How do I get the i2c-dev module etc. to load at bootup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the module loads using `sudo modprobe i2c-dev`, you should add `i2c-dev` to `/etc/modules`.

Comment: for clarification for us non-linux guys. "modules" is the file, it has no file name extension.

Answer (score 7):

They are blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf

```
# blacklist spi and i2c by default (many users don't need them)

blacklist spi-bcm2708
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

so comment these lines.

Comment: I uncommented them. `spidev`, `spi-bcm2708` and `i2c-bcm2708` all loaded, but `i2c-dev` didn't so I guess I still need it in `/etc/modules`

Comment: Why on earth would they blacklist these!?!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain because an average user don't need those modules. From modprobe.conf man page:  There are cases where two or more modules both support the same devices, or a module invalidly claims to support a device: the blacklist keyword indicates that all of a particular module's internal aliases are to be ignored. [ http://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.conf ]